# Number of item submit in PagingDataAdapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-paging-3

> How to get number of items submitted to **PagingDataAdapter**

I have to display a **RecyclerView** with multiple `viewType` as **Start**, **Middle** and **End** RecyclerView.ViewHolder

Start and End ViewHolder is round where as inner items are using MiddleViewHolder

[image]

After debug I evaluate that when i submit 2 items to **PagingDataAdapter**
itemCount is still 1.

How to check total item submit in PagingDataAdapter

StartViewHolder ->  `bindData(item,itemCount == 1)`

**RecentPagerAdapter.kt**

```
const val VIEW_TYPE_FIRST = 0
const val VIEW_TYPE_MIDDLE = 1
private const val VIEW_TYPE_LAST = 2
class RecentPagerAdapter(val clicked:(recent:RecentBO) -> Unit) : PagingDataAdapter<RecentBO, RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(recentDiffUtil) {

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {

        getItem(position)?.let { item ->
            when (getItemViewType(position)) {
                VIEW_TYPE_FIRST -> (holder as StartViewHolder).bindData(item,itemCount == 1)
                VIEW_TYPE_MIDDLE -> (holder as RecentViewHolder).bindData(item)
                VIEW_TYPE_LAST -> (holder as EndViewHolder).bindData(item)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        return when (position) {
            0 -> VIEW_TYPE_FIRST
            1 -> VIEW_TYPE_MIDDLE
            else -> VIEW_TYPE_LAST
        }
    }
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        return when(viewType) {
            VIEW_TYPE_FIRST -> StartViewHolder(ItemCurveStartBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),parent,false)){
                getItem(it)?.let { clicked.invoke(it) }
            }
            VIEW_TYPE_LAST -> EndViewHolder(ItemCurveEndBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),parent,false)){
                getItem(it)?.let { clicked.invoke(it) }
            }
            else -> RecentViewHolder(ItemRecentBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),parent,false)){
                getItem(it)?.let { clicked.invoke(it) }
            }
        }
    }

    companion object {
        private val recentDiffUtil = object : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<RecentBO>() {
            override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: RecentBO, newItem: RecentBO): Boolean {
                return oldItem.localPath == newItem.localPath && oldItem.imageUrl == newItem.imageUrl
            }

            override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: RecentBO, newItem: RecentBO): Boolean {
                return oldItem == newItem
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If there is only one item in list then all sides should be rounded.otherwise above image and last item should be rounded also.

**StartViewHolder.kt**

```
class StartViewHolder(val itemBinding: ItemCurveStartBinding,
                       val clicked:(pos:Int) -> Unit): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemBinding.root) ,
    View.OnClickListener{

    init {
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this)
    }
    fun bindData(recentBO: RecentBO,onlyOneItem:Boolean){
        itemBinding.item = recentBO
        val radius: Float = 30.0f//getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.default_corner_radius)

        if(onlyOneItem){
            itemBinding.ivPhoto.shapeAppearanceModel = itemBinding.ivPhoto.shapeAppearanceModel
                .toBuilder()
                .setTopLeftCorner(CornerFamily.ROUNDED,radius)
                .setBottomLeftCorner(CornerFamily.ROUNDED,radius)
                .setTopRightCorner(CornerFamily.ROUNDED,radius)
                .setBottomRightCorner(CornerFamily.ROUNDED,radius)
                .build();
        }else {
            itemBinding.ivPhoto.shapeAppearanceModel = itemBinding.ivPhoto.shapeAppearanceModel
                .toBuilder()
                .setTopLeftCorner(CornerFamily.ROUNDED,radius)
                .setBottomLeftCorner(CornerFamily.ROUNDED,radius)
                .build();
        }
    }

    override fun onClick(p0: View?) {
        clicked.invoke(absoluteAdapterPosition)
    }
}
```

I think something mistake in below code

```
(holder as StartViewHolder).bindData(item,itemCount == 1)
```

there are 2 items in RecyclerView but itemCount shows 1

What am i missing or doing wrong??

When I added an item to it First item remain fully rounded.

Code for initializing adapter

```
private val recentPagerAdapter by lazy { RecentPagerAdapter{
        openPreview(PhotoBO(it.localPath))
    }

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    mViewModel.getRecentPhotos().observe(viewLifecycleOwner)
    {
            recentPagerAdapter
             .submitData(viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycle,it)
            recentPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}
```

**Please See Edit**
`itemCount` and `snapshot().items.size` is **1**  where as I have submitData 2 items to `PagingDataAdapter`

How to know total item submitted to **PagingDataAdapter** inside `onBindViewHolder` ?

Comment: Can you post the code where you initialize your `RecentPagerAdapter` instance?

Comment: @LucaPizzini I have added code to initializing

Comment: with submitData, you dont need to call notifyDataSetChanged. In this case, could you change your adapter to RecyclerView.Adapter for testing why your data only has 1, it's so tricky

Comment: I have tried with both way

Comment: Please See Edit part of my question..

Comment: Can you post your `getRecentPhotos()` method code from the view model?